# How to use mdx-deck with react-redux?

Tags: react-redux

I'm making web slides using this awesome library called [mdx-deck](https://github.com/jxnblk/mdx-deck). I've written my own React components for my slide deck. Now I want to add [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start) to my slide deck so that all components share a common store. How can I do this?

I know I should use the `<Provider />` component from `react-redux`, so I've been reading about [mdx-deck custom provider](https://github.com/jxnblk/mdx-deck/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#custom-provider-component) and [MDXProvider](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/blob/master/docs/getting-started/index.md#mdxprovider), but I haven't been able to see the `<Provider />` in my DOM.

I'm using `yarn start` to serve my slide deck:

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "mdx-deck concat-slides.js",
  }
}
```

The `concat-slides.js` script concatenates two slide decks that I have:

```
// concat-slides.js
import { slides as cv } from 'src/slides/cv.mdx';
import { slides as bootstrap } from 'src/slides/bootstrap.mdx';
import { distillLite } from 'src/slides/theme/index';

export const themes = [distillLite];
export const slides = [...cv, ...bootstrap]
```

And here's my attempt to add a custom provider (but I don't see a provider in my DOM tree?):

```
// src/slides/theme/index.tsx

import React from 'react'
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from "react-redux";

export const store = createStore(() => {});

const Provider = (props:any) => (
  <ReduxProvider store={store}>
    {props.children}
  </ReduxProvider>
)

export const distillLite = {
  Provider,
}
```